# How can I get json data thru ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a chart page that updates every 5 seconds based on flotr2. But I'm having some problems with the return from the server, I get

```
[object, Object],[object, Object],[object, Object],[object, Object],[object, Object],[object, Object],[object, Object]
```

The javascript looks like:

```
    function updateFunc() {

        new Ajax.Request('http://localhost:53083/Home/Data', {
            method: 'get',
            onSuccess: function (transport) {
                var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                alert(json);
            }
        });
    }

    updateFunc();
```

And the asp.net/c# looks like:

```
        //
        // GET: /Home/Data

        public string Data()
        {
            dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);

            dt.Rows.Add(rand.Next(1, 50));

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
        }
```

dt is just a static datatable where i remove the first and add a new, creating a feel of continuous update.

What is wrong? As posted all i get is the `[object, Object]` from the alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to change the response's media type to say it is JSON so the client will interpret it correctly:

   ```
   Response.ContentType = "application/json";
   ```

   (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/477816/67392) for the reference to the correct type.)
2. It appears that `JsonConvert` doesn't know how to serialise the type of `dt`. Either change to a type 
   that it can serialise, or tell it how to serialise that type: see the [JSON.Net documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.aspx).